# Internal testing app's size shows in the Google Play Store changes inexplicably

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I uploaded a aab package to the Google Console for internal testing. After uploaded, about 1 hour later, I checked app info shows in the Google Play Store on my Samsung Galaxy S8 device, in the app description page, it showed 100MB download size (no early version installed in the device).
And one day later, I checked again with the same device, it showed 95MB. I am sure nothing changes in this same device, I just putted it there and didn't touch it, and one day later the value changed.
Can anyone tell why this value changes?

It is reasonable that value changes if I changes device's os version or language, but this time I did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Google takes some time to process the app bundle and generate update patches which will be smaller than downloading the whole app.

Comment: The phenomenon I met match what you say here.